# Show that if $x$ and $y$ are both irrational, then at least one of $x\pm y$ is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove that, for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, if $x$ and $y$ are irrational, then $x + y$ and
>   $x − y$ are not both rational. How to solve it?

What I have;

Suppose that $x+y$ is either irrational or rational. If irrational, then done.

If $x + y$ is rational,  then I need to show that $x - y$ is irrational. To prove that, I use contradiction, and assume that x - y is rational. I set up the equation $x - y = a/b$, where $x, y$ are in $R/Q$ and $a, b \in\mathbb Z$. I add $2y$ to both sides, to get $x + y = a / b + 2y$. I use a lemma to state that $2y$ is irrational, and another one to state that $a/b + 2y$ is irrational. This arrives at a contradiction that $x + y$ is irrational, hence it must be that $x - y$ is irrational.

And since in both scenarios neither $x+y$ nor $x-y$ are both rational

Comment: Assume both $(x+y)$ and $(x-y)$ *rational*; then $(x+y)+(x-y)$ is *rational*.

Comment: assume x+y, x-y are both rational
then I can say x - y = a / b, and x + y = c / d
add, and get 2x = a / b + c / d
and x = something rational, that also works since it is contradicting that x is irrational

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why are you answering in a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stronger statement can be proved:$$\text{if at least one of }x\text{ and }y\text{ is not rational then at least one of }x+y\text{ and }x-y\text{ is not rational}$$

or equivalently:$$\text{if }x+y\text{ and }x-y\text{ are both rational then }x\text{ and }y\text{ are both rational}$$

Observe that the premise implies that $2x=(x+y)+(x-y)$ and $2y=(x+y)-(x-y)$ are both rational, and consequently $x$ and $y$ are both rational.